# Convergence of $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I'm interesting to see the opinion of MO about my question which I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822112) in SE, Answers I received have not convinced me, And no clear proof posted there only numerical computation are provided. I should post the question as it is in order to know more about convergence of the titled sequence

**Question**:
let us moving to telescopic sum using exponent, Assume we have this sequence: $a_n=(1-\frac12)^{(\frac12-\frac13)^{...^{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}}}$ with $n\geq1$, this sequence can be written as power of sequences: ${x_n} ^ {{{y_n}^{c_n}}^\cdots} $ such that all them value are in $(0,1)$, I want to know if the titled sequence should converge to $1$? and how we can evaluate it for $n$ go to $\infty$?

Comment: [Cross-posted from Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822112/convergence-of-a-n-1-frac12-frac12-frac13-frac1n-frac1n) (using a different account?)

Comment: I can't ask questions in my original account that is the reason i created a new account

Comment: A few extra pieces of information seem helpful, I think (since I already spent some time with this on MSE): (1) The expression is meant to be unwrapped starting at the right end; (2) a plausible conjecture is that this has two accumulation points, approached along even and odd $n$, respectively.

Comment: Denoting by a and b with  $ a<b $ the two plausible accumulation points, it seems that  $ ab+b/a $ is close to 2.

Comment: @Sylvain, every real number is close to 2 (except, of course, 2 itself).

Comment: "I can't ask questions in my original account that is the reason i created a new account" Can you please clarify this? You're not saying you're under a question ban on one account, so you've opened a new account to evade the ban, are you?

Comment: yes , i"'m under  ban however i asked community to open my account at a least to know the reason why they closed it for asking

Comment: @ZeraouliRafik: Barry Cipra's answer in the stackexchange question answers your first question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2826712/32285 As for your second question, the sequence $a_n$ might not converge, but one can show (using Barry Cipra's argument) that $a_{2n}$ is decreasing, $a_{2n+1}$ is increasing, such that $a_{2n+1} < a_{2m}$, and hence each sequence has a limit. It appears that numerically the two subsequences have different limits, and hence it seems unlikely that the sequence $a_n$ has a limit. So I'm guessing that both of your questions are unfounded.

Comment: There is no need to cross-post this to Mathoverflow. The abovementioned question ban does not seem entirely unfounded.